# Design issue - thread safety of Async requests in servlets

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, concurrency, jetty

Section `2.3.3.4` of Servlet 3.0 Spec reads-

> Other than the startAsync and complete methods, implementations of the
>   request and response objects are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>   This means that  they should either only be used within the scope of
>   the request handling thread or  the application must ensure that
>   access to the request and response objects are  thread safe.

I am using Jetty and my question is -

My requirement is to read the request's ServletInputStream in my async thread which is processing request. Now, if I were to read http headers etc, it will be easy. I can read them before I start async and pass onto the thread.

But, in my case I need to use ServletInputStream as I don't want to buffer the content before I pass onto processing thread.

Is there a way I can solve this problem? Or, if I just pass reference of ServletInputStream to processing thread, will I be just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you make sure that only one thread is reading from the ServletInputStream at any one time you will be fine.